# Как настроить Telegram бота на python, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку приходило уведомление в определенное время

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Мне нужно, чтобы на определенное событие приходило в два дня в неделю, вторник и воскресенье, например, в 20:55 уведомление о том, что какое-то событие начнется через 5 минут. Возможно ли?

Comment: Через aiogram думаю да. К тому же довольно просто

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно, чтобы если человек забыл о событии, то бот ему об этом напомнил

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе известно во сколько именно начинается событие можешь воспользоваться стандартной библиотекой datetime в питоне

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]